# How do I get the color value from the List<Feature> list?

Tags: java, android, dictionary, mapbox

I have specified the colors of `object2.addProperty("marker-colors", "#ffbf00");` in json to then retrieve the value. `withImage(ICON_ID, createBitMap(get("marker-color")))`

I will use color value in createBitmap(...)

here my code

```
List<Feature> features = new ArrayList<>();

        JsonObject object1 = new JsonObject();
        object1.addProperty("title", "TEST1");
        object1.addProperty("marker-color", "#c70024");
        features.add(Feature.fromGeometry(
                Point.fromLngLat(106.535033, -6.323488), object1));

        JsonObject object2 = new JsonObject();
        object2.addProperty("title", "TEST2");
        object2.addProperty("marker-color", "#ffbf00");
        features.add(Feature.fromGeometry(
                Point.fromLngLat(106.897423, -6.277078), object2));

        JsonObject object3 = new JsonObject();
        object3.addProperty("title", "TEST3");
        object3.addProperty("marker-color", "#00c753");
        features.add(Feature.fromGeometry(
                Point.fromLngLat(106.797217, -6.171958), object3));
```

then

```
mapboxMap.setStyle(new Style.Builder().fromUri(CPN_STYLE)
                .withSource(new GeoJsonSource(SOURCE_ID,
                        FeatureCollection.fromFeatures(features)))
                .withImage(ICON_ID, createBitMap(get("marker-color")))
                .withLayer(new SymbolLayer(LAYER_ID, SOURCE_ID)
                        .withProperties(
                                textField(get("title")),
                                iconImage(ICON_ID),
                                textSize(14f),
                                iconAllowOverlap(true),
                                iconIgnorePlacement(true),
                                textColor(get("marker-color")),
                                textJustify(TEXT_JUSTIFY_AUTO),
                                iconOffset(new Float[]{0f, -9f}))
                ), style -> {

            mapboxMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(
                                new CameraPosition.Builder()
                                        .target(new LatLng(-6.323488, 106.535033))
                                        .zoom(7)
                                        .build()), 1000);

        });
```

The answer will be very useful. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do the following instead of using `JsonObject`s

```
Feature singleFeature = Feature.fromGeometry(Point.fromLngLat(LONG,LAT));
singleFeature.addStringProperty("title", "TEST1");
singleFeature.addStringProperty("marker-color", "#c70024");
features.add(singleFeature);
```

What's the `createBitmap()` method look like under the hood?

You'll probably want to use the Maps SDK's `MapView.OnStyleImageMissingListener` and closely follow what's done in https://docs.mapbox.com/android/maps/examples/missing-icon/.

1. Don't use `.withImage()` as you set up the SymbolLayer.
2. It'll be `.iconImage(get("marker-color")),` for your SymbolLayer.

Comment: Awesome! Glad to hear it.